# How do I view/fix errors on static-content:deploy?

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1, cli, static-content

I am installing a theme and when I run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` I get an error on some of the themes eg:

```
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US === ... Successful: 1997 files; errors: 1
```

how do I see what these errors are so I can fix them, or can I ignore these?

I am using a fresh install of Magento 2.1, in developer mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add more verbosity to the command by adding `-vvv` for example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vvv
```

It will output debug verbosity and could help you fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael at Digital Pianism I get the following error
'[Exception] Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=368675 in  /public_html/mag2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228' (also shows a large list of Exception trace)

Comment: @pnx well please open a new question with the full trace as this is a different question. Also feel free to mark that question as answered so it will benefit for others

Comment: thanks, I have opened a new question with the full error